# Does SpaceX's Starship have aerodynamic problems due to its thin skin?

Tags: spacex

Looking at the Starship it looks bumpy, like the skin is buckling in places.  Is that a problem?  If so, how big a problem?  If not, why not?  I'm thinking specifically about aerodynamic problems here, but if there are other problems (or non-issues) I'm open to learning.

Comment: I think the thing you are looking at pictures of is a test article used to work out integration issues and isn't flight hardware.

Comment: @zeta-band are you saying the ratty-looking Starship displayed in Boca Chica is not a flight article?  That's contrary to what was reported in the press. "This thing is going to take off, fly to 65,000 feet — about 20 kilometers — and come back and land in about one to two months,” Musk said, referring to the stainless steel prototype behind him." https://www.theverge.com/2019/9/29/20889605/spacex-elon-musk-starship-rocket-update-pictures-mk1  BTW, it's now been one month, for those keeping track of Musk Time

Comment: Was "this thing" explicitly referring to the one behind him? It's a controls nightmare I don't even think there are enough Merlin's in existence to fill the bottom right now.

Comment: @mothman It is going to be filled by Raptors. The early test article will just need from 3 to 6 engines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship#Starhopper) which they may have already (i.e. months ago they were already flying a Raptor engine with serial number 6..)

Comment: @BlueCoder yup, I thought Merlin's for some reason. Is the 3-6 there referring to starhopper, not the starship?

Comment: @mothman Starhopper had only one and its job is finished with success: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYb3bfA6_sQ
Now it's Starship Mk 1 time!
I confirm Starship will have 6 Raptors in the end, see https://youtu.be/sOpMrVnjYeY?t=1166
It might be just 3 for the next test with Mk1 (suborbital, 20km altitude): https://www.space.com/spacex-starship-reach-orbit-six-months.html